# Error in Phonegap navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

Tags: android, cordova

When I try to get my geographical position in my HTML page I get the following error:
Error code: 2
Error message: The last location provider is no longer available
here is my code:

```
// onSuccess Callback
//  This method accepts a `Position` object, which contains
//  the current GPS coordinates
//
var onSuccess = function(position) {
   };

var HospitalsRecord = [];



//onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
   alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
         'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}

// Cordova is ready
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError, { maximumAge: Infinity, timeout: 15000, enableHighAccuracy: true });

}

// Wait for Cordova to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


</script>
```

why is it happening?

thanks in advance

Kobi

Comment: Check if you have `android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this to your config.xml, which is located in the root of your application:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
```

This could be added anywhere within the widget tag. It helped for me.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this..

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        // Wait for Cordova to load 

        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready      

        function onDeviceReady() {

            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);

        }

        // onSuccess Geolocation      

        function onSuccess(position) {

            var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');

            element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: ' + position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +

                            'Longitude: ' + position.coords.longitude + '<br />' +

                            'Altitude: ' + position.coords.altitude + '<br />' +

                            'Accuracy: ' + position.coords.accuracy + '<br />' +

                            'Altitude Accuracy: ' + position.coords.altitudeAccuracy + '<br />' +

                            'Heading: ' + position.coords.heading + '<br />' +

                            'Speed: ' + position.coords.speed + '<br />' +

                            'Timestamp: ' + position.timestamp + '<br />';

        }

        // onError Callback receives a PositionError object     

        function onError(error) {

            alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +

              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');

        }

    </script>
```

For more information..

[try this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c25b6d/geolocation-in-phonegap/)